# WiFi internet not working for only one single device

Tags: wireless-networking, android

I have a Netgear WNR614 WiFi router and whenever I try to connect to it using my Samsung Galaxy S20Ultra the internet works for a minute or so and then it shows no internet connection available. It works fine on all other devices and it also works fine if I use the WiFi through another phone using WiFi sharing option in other mobile phone's hotspot, but not directly. I can't understand why.

Comment: That’s a really old router. It runs only on the 2.4Ghz band. It’s likely there is either an incompatibility or more likely nearby interference that these two devices simply can’t tolerate together. If you’re in any moderately populated area this is most likely the issue. Getting closer to the router might help, but is by no means a way of proving / ruling out interference.

Comment: I was thinking about changing the router but I thought since it was only on one device it must be something else. But I guess it was router specific. Thank you for the help